# CSS transition not working on visited links

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to implement CSS transition on the hyperlinks, I'm trying following code, but it is only working on un-visited links. It does not work on the visited links. Am i doing anything wrong?

```
a, a:link, a:visited {
    color: lightblue;
    -webkit-transition: color .4s linear;
    -moz-transition: color .4s linear;
    -o-transition: color .4s linear;
    -ms-transition: color .4s linear;
    transition: color .4s linear;
    }

    a:hover {
        color: red;
    }
```

There is no any other CSS code which could conflict with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's not working for you most likely is that you're testing the functionality in Chrome. Check out this link:

[CSS3 color transition not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490828/css3-color-transition-not-working-in-chrome)

Answer (score 2):

CSS Psuedo-classes have to come one after the other in order to work:

```
a { /* code */ }
a:link { /* code */ }
a:visited  { /* code */ }
a:hover { /* code */ }
```

Also note, the sequence in which these are written matters.

Comment: If your :link and :visited pseudo elements are the same (as in your case above) they're probably not necessary either. I'd just drop back to `a{ /*code*/ }` for the first rule and be done with it - test it out and see if you see any differences.