# Why does this hover transition not work in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, css, css-transitions

I've been thinking about **[this issue](https://bitbucket.org/GloverDonovan/vivid-imagination/issue/2/tint-transition-effect-not-working-in)** for the past few days but I can't figure out what exactly is the problem.

Consider the following snippet from **[style.css](https://bitbucket.org/GloverDonovan/vivid-imagination/src/4e4a7e614fe14936bd58b95b567df42c88bfba8e/style.css)**:

```
.tint:before {
        -moz-transition: all .3s linear;
     -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
         -ms-transition: all .3s linear;
          -o-transition: all .3s linear;
             transition: all .3s linear;
}
.tint:hover:before {background:rgba(159,182,205,0.1);}
```

As you can see from the code above, upon an image hover, a "tint" transition should occur as to make the user want to click on that image. However, this feature does not work in Chrome.

Why does the hover transition not work in Chrome yet works perfectly fine in Firefox?

Is this the expected behavior? Or does Chrome not render these transitions correctly?

Comment: I get the feeling people recently are using some bugged beta version of Chrome :D It works for me. :)

Comment: @KaloyanIvanov What version of Chrome do you have?

Comment: It says 26.0.1410.64 m

Comment: Please spell out where the effect is / what it should be to make it easier for us to see if we have the same issue with our Chrome version(s).

Comment: Any relation to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8490828/631619 ?

Comment: @KaloyanIvanov Ahaha... I was using Chrome 25.0.1323.1 m, a dev release of Chrome back in November. Upgrading to the latest stable build of 26.0.1410.64 m solved the issue.

Comment: Applying CSS transitions to pseudo-elements isn't supported by the following browsers: IE9-, Chrome 25-, Safari, Opera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to the :before pseudo class.  It doesn't seem like hover is being triggered on that class.  If you remove it, it works just fine.

```
.tint {
 -moz-transition: all .3s linear;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
 -ms-transition: all .3s linear;
 -o-transition: all .3s linear;
 transition: all .3s linear;
}
.tint:hover{background:rgba(159,182,205,0.1);}
```

Here is the jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qGAn9/

**UPDATE:**

If :before pseudo element is needed, then you can trigger the hover on the parent element.  I also had to add some additional styles to make the pseudo element appear on top.

```
.tint:before {
     -moz-transition: all .3s linear;
     -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
     -ms-transition: all .3s linear;
     -o-transition: all .3s linear;
     transition: all .3s linear;

    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.tint:hover:before{background:rgba(159,182,205,0.5);}
```

jsFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/qGAn9/2/

Comment: The `:before` is explicitly declared so that the tint transition works on top of the images. Not using `:before` will prevent the transition from being shown on top of the images.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: To use `:hover:before`, [IE10 requires](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-animationstransitions-bug-fixed-in-webkit/) that a `:hover` CSS rule is also defined (which can be empty).