# Hover transition only working on first instance in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, hover, css-transitions

This should be a simple thing: four linked SVGs in an inline list, each with a smooth transition from grey to colour on hover. However, **in Chrome, only the first item in my list transitions - the others do not**. The transitions work as expected for all items in Firefox.

Jump to it on JS Fiddle, or see the snippets below: http://jsfiddle.net/chicgeek/NZpXs/1/

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
.social svg {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}
.social path {
  fill: #ccc;
  -moz-transition: all .8s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all .8s linear;
  -ms-transition: all .8s linear;
  -o-transition: all .8s linear;
  transition: all .8s linear;
}
.social a:hover path.twitter {
  fill: #4099FF;
}
.social a:hover path.facebook {
  fill: #3B5998;
}
.social a:hover path.github {
  fill: #171515;
}
.social a:hover path.linkedin {
  fill: #0e76a8;
}
```

And the markup [truncated]:

```
<section class="social">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">
      <svg ...>
      <path class="twitter" d="..."/></svg>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">
      <svg ...>
      <path class="facebook" d="..."></path></svg>
    </a></li>
    <...>
  </ul>
</section>
```

The `:hover` style works as expected, but there is no transition. The inspector in Chrome shows that the `.social path` selector is fine (they all display `fill: #ccc;` to confirm this, too).

- Is there something wrong with my selectors or how I put this together? (that is, where have I screwed up?)
- Is this a Chrome bug? If so, what's the workaround?
- While we're at it, do I still need to use vendor prefixes for `transition`? (Changing this didn't solve my issue, anyway...)

I've done my best to scour existing questions here for a solution to this with no luck. Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More investigating and I've determined it is a known Chrome bug. Chrome seems to have issues with applying transitions to visited links.

For the example above, it always works impeccably in incognito mode.

For more information:

- [CSS3 color transition not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490828/css3-color-transition-not-working-in-chrome)
- [Chromium Issue 101245: Once a link has been visited CSS transitions no longer work](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=101245&q=visited%20transition&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary)

Comment: That's funny because the fiddle works on my chrome 28.0.1500.72 m

Comment: Likely because you haven't visited the links. :) Click through on one or two and try again.