# css animation moves but doesn't change the color

Tags: html, css, animation, colors

Here is the CSS code

```
@keyframes anim{
  0% {background-color: red; top: 0px; }
  100% {background-color: yellow; top: calc(100vh - 110px);}
}

.circle {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: anim;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}


#button {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

#button:target {
  animation-name: anim;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;  

}
```

And HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
      CSS anim
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='circle'>
  </div>
  <a href="#button">
    <div id="button">
    </div>
  </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

So when I click on the #button div, (ignore the .circle) it goes down and stays there as it is intended in the animation. But it doesn't change the color. Why and how to fix it ?

Comment: The code you have posted in question seems to work fine. It does change the color once clicked (during the animation). Check if any other selector is overriding your setting. Else, create a demo where we can see the problem.

Comment: [example](http://jsbin.com/pujerocife/edit?html,css,output)

No not in my computer.

Comment: Please mention the browser you are using.

Comment: @HaykSafaryan: That JSBin works as expected.

Comment: @Harry For me, It does not work in Google Chrome 46.0.2490.80 but works perfectly fine on FF 41.0.2

Comment: @ManojKumar: I am on Chrome too (Version 48.0.2535.0 dev-m) and it works.

Comment: Yes it is because of Chrome, is there any work around for version 46?

Comment: This issue is a well known chrome bug, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490828/css3-color-transition-not-working-in-chrome . If you remove the :target selector, it will work.